# How do I convert the string "5 April 2011" into a date object in Ruby 1.9.2?

Tags: ruby

I'm quite sure this is trivial, but for the life of me I can't seem to find a reference.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Bear in mind that Date.parse is insanely slow. It's probably the slowest thing in the whole Ruby stdlib. If you're going to use it more than once, I strongly suggest you use home_run (https://github.com/jeremyevans/home_run), a drop-in replacement for Date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Date#parse](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/Date.html#M000358)

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :008 > d = Date.parse("5 April 2011")
 => Tue, 05 Apr 2011 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :009 > d.class
 => Date
```

now you can do things such as:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :018 > d.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
 => "05-04-2011"
```

Answer (score 4):

Besides `Date.parse` there's also `Date.strptime`, the reverse of `strftime`:

```
Date.strptime('5 April 2011', '%d %B %Y')
```

But `Date.parse` and `Date.strptime` are both insanely slow (`strptime` a little less so, but still really bad). Consider using [home_run](https://github.com/jeremyevans/home_run) if you're going to do anything more than than the occasional call. `home_run` is a drop-in replacement for the `Date` and `DateTime` classes.

Comment: +1 for the pointer to home_run. Maybe we'll see Ruby incorporate it as a replacement for the current Date/DateTime libraries.

Answer (score 2):

```
>> date = Date.parse('5 april 2011')
=> #<Date: 2011-04-05 (4911313/2,0,2299161)>
>> date.strftime("%D")
=> "04/05/11"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't trust `Date.parse` to magically get it right (I certainly don't trust it), I recommend that you use `Date.strptime` to exactly specify the format that it should parse:

```
require 'date'
Date.strptime "5 April 2011", '%d %B %Y'
#=> #<Date: 2011-04-05 (4911313/2,0,2299161)>
```

The codes you use to specify the format are basically the same as [`Time#strftime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000392).